# How to solve this differential equation: $\rho \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+au+bu^3+c(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})^2=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I need to solve the following differential equation:

$\rho \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+au+bu^3+c(\frac{\partial u}{dx})^2=0$

If I ignore the spatial derivative term "$(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})^2$", I can numerically solve it using ode45 function of MATLAB. But I don't know how to do with the last term in it.

I considered "method of lines", but there are two problems-

a) The spatial derivative term is 2nd order, and therefore it cannot be discretized

b) There is a $u^3$ term, I think such term cannot be represented in the vector space.

Comment: You should use partial derivatives, this is a PDE. Is the spatial derivative second degree or second order ?

Comment: Sorry, it is second order. I corrected the description.

Comment: But you didn't fix the notation.

Comment: It is fixed now.....

Comment: The spatial derivative is still a second degree, sorry.

Comment: The way the equation is written is the one I am dealing with. It has this second degree spatial derivative term. I am sorry for getting confused with the terminology.

Comment: Just use an implicit-explicit (IMEX) scheme, discretising the linear terms implicitly and the nonlinear terms explicitly. However, there are numerous packages you can use for free to solve this PDE for you so you don't have to code it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Mattos.
Can you please give some reference?